# Can't remove event listeners in React in children components

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have a parent react component that has methods to add and remove listeners. It looks like this:

```
const onKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    //Some stuff
    e.preventDefault();
};

const addEventListeners = () => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
};

const removeEventListeners = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
};
```

I pass down both addEventListeners and removeEventListeners to some children components because I want them to add and remove listeners. The problem is that only addEventListeners works, meanwhile removeEventListeners doesn't seem to work. addEventListeners is executed as many times as removeEventListeners.